# Create relationship between two tables with composite primary key

Tags: sql-server-2012, foreign-key, primary-key, relational-theory

I've created a table `[t1]` with two fields and a composite primary key, show in below:

```
create table t1(
    id int,
    name nchar(10),
    primary key(id,name)
);
```

I want to create a second table `[t2]` that has a relationship with `[t1]`, but I get an error with the below create table script:

```
create table t2(
    id int references t1(id),
    name nchar(10) references t1(name),
    primary key(id,name)
);
```

This the error message:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 't1' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__t2__id__33D4B598'.

Comment: Also -- though it doesn't solve your problem -- the second statement contains an error: the column `phone` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

A multiple-column foreign key constraint must be declared at the table level, not on each column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    name nchar(10) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_t1_id_name
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id,name)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.t2
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    name nchar(10) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_t2_id_name
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id,name),

    CONSTRAINT FK_dbo_t2_t1_id_name
    FOREIGN KEY (id, name) 
    REFERENCES dbo.t1 (id, name)
);
```

Comment: +1 Also he is doing `primary key(id,phone)` on `t2` but `t2` has no `phone` column.

Comment: the primary key is(id,name). if changed the "phone" to "name" it has the same error.